# Get list of IDs of Facebook post likers, commenters and sharers?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get the actual Facebook IDs of all people who liked, commented (+replied to comments or liked comments) or shared a post (e.g. a post by a person or a FB page).

Looking for a programmatic solution in PHP.

(I am not familiar with programming for Facebook and their API)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to try to dive in a topic yourself before asking help. These kind of questions are all over internet and are easy to find.

That said; you can use the [/sharedposts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/sharedposts) edge on Graph Objects. Starting from there, you can dive into the documentation of the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3).

**edit**: To be more explicit, you **can't** just get **all of the people**. You have to use the `/sharedposts` endpoint to get the posts. You will only receive the posts that are accessible to your app; e.g. specific user (privacy) settings are taken into account.

If you have the ID of a post, say `1234_5678`, you can get these by calling:

https://graph.facebook.com/1234_5678/sharedposts?access_token=[access_token]

If you are unfamiliar with the Facebook Graph API, asking for just the code won't help; it's not a single call and you would need to implement authentication / app access token. So that's why you need to dive in yourself; the documentation is pretty good resource to get started.

Comment: I have already searched quite a lot before putting the question. The only closest info I found was "how to get the number of likers" but not the actual IDs. If you can give a link to a code which shows what I am asking for - that would be an answer.